# Cursor in stored procedure finishes and get stuck (Oracle 11g on Oracle Linux VM)

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have Oracle Linux 11g installed in Oracle VM VirutalBox. (4GB RAM allocated)
I have a user with several tables. I've created a procedure in this user's schema, which uses a cursor,  :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_STATS (p_emp_id IN number)
IS
     v_name     varchar2(50);
     CURSOR c_stat IS
       SELECT J.IS_DESCRIPTION as st_name, count(*) AS st_count 
       FROM inventory I , inventory_status J
       WHERE I.STATUS=J.IS_ID and I.EMPLOYEE_ID = p_emp_id
       GROUP BY J.IS_DESCRIPTION;
       c_stat_rec c_stat%rowtype;
BEGIN
       IF NOT c_stat%ISOPEN THEN 
          OPEN c_stat;
     END IF;
       SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
       INTO v_name
       FROM employees
       WHERE employee_id = p_emp_id;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Employee ' || v_name || ' Stats:');
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('-----------------------------------------');

       LOOP
           FETCH c_stat INTO c_stat_rec ;
           EXIT WHEN c_stat%NOTFOUND ;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (c_stat_rec.st_count || ' items in status ' || c_stat_rec.st_name);
       END LOOP;

END;
```

The procedure is compiled successfully.
When I test the procedure on PL/SQL Developer on my laptop (Win8) - It get stuck after It runs the procedure. I.e., when I test via a simple block:

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  show_stats(10004);
end;
```

I've tried the SELECT statement in the cursor - it runs and gives output.

The debug runs over the procedure okay (For some reason, no output), but when it steps out of the procedure I get the sand-watch treatment and the PL/SQL client gets stuck and I have to crash it.

Can anyone has a lead to why it happens?

Comment: Which window are you running the call from, and are you seeing any of the dbms_output? If you see what's there, if you add another message after the loop do you see that? Does closing the cursor at the end make any difference? (It shouldn't but maybe that's confusing the debugger?) Can you run it from another client, like SQL\*Plus inside the VM?

Comment: I run Windows 8.1 
I don't see any DBMS_OUTPUT output which also puzzles me. Closing the cursor doesn't have any effect. When I run the block from the sql*plus in the VM, I just get a message that the block is compiled successfully

Comment: Update :When I run the block from SQL*Plus, I DO see the results okay when I do 'Exec show_stats(<>);' (I forget to set the server output on). The same when I ran sql plus on the windows. So - the question is , why does the pl/sql get stuck

Comment: I meant which PL/SQL Developer window (SQL, command, test... I don't have it running so can't remember the others) not which version of Windows. Do you see the output there too now? Otherwise why do you think it's stuck after the procedure, rather than in the loop, say (not that it should stick there either).

Comment: I user Test window on the procedure., and run it in debug mode.
Anyway, I tried to isolate the command that supposedly causing the problem, and It seems that the SELECT INTO statement is the problem for some reason,

Comment: Moreover, The problems occurs again if I only put the SELECT INTO statement & the DBMS_OUTPUT that prints the variable (v_name) and only if the two commands exist. (if I just use SELECT INTO, the block compiles okay)

Comment: Update : SQL developer also works fine. I'm beginning to suspect my PL/SQL Developer is just f***ed.

Comment: It certainly looks like a PL/SQL bug, but I'm not familiar enough with it to recognise it or help much - was mostly hoping to tease out info so someone else could jump in. Does just removing all the dbms_output calls make any difference? I've changed the tags to hopefully get more appropriate eyes on this. Good luck.

Comment: I believe @AlexPoole is correct, try removing the dbms_output calls and let us know of the impact.

Comment: Looks ok to me, so I guess PL/SQL-Developer hates you. Create a procedure that just does a few lines of DBMS_OUTPUT and check what happens when you run it in PL/SQL-Developer.

Comment: Okay, I've upgraded from PLSQL DEV 8 to 9 and what do you know? the whole code works fine !!! :-)

Comment: end your procedure with `/`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a cursor like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_STATS (p_emp_id IN number)
is
v_name varchar2(100);
begin
       SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name
       INTO v_name
       FROM employees
       WHERE employee_id = p_emp_id;
for i in (
SELECT J.IS_DESCRIPTION as st_name, count(*) AS st_count 
       FROM inventory I , inventory_status J
       WHERE I.STATUS=J.IS_ID and I.EMPLOYEE_ID = p_emp_id
       GROUP BY J.IS_DESCRIPTION) loop
end loop;
exception
when others then
   dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);

end;
```

So you do not have to worry to close the cursor which is not in your procedure

Answer (score 0):

You need to end your procedure with `/`

```
PLSQL code
END;
/
```

Comment: The procedure is compiled successfully, and runs from other clients (including a later version of the same client), so that isn't the issue.